# Why do loose parts of clothing keep stretching after rigging?

Tags: mesh, rigging, weight-painting

I know this may seem like a duplicate but it's not because I've gone through so many tutorials and nothing fixes this problem.

I've rigged up my character and small parts of their clothing(like high socks, long collar on the shirt, things like that) will stretch towards the center when I test the armature and I've gone to weight painting and painted the offending vertices and meshes but it still doesn't fix it and I am really, really stuck here.

I've been stuck on this problem for literal months going through well over a hundred tutorials and getting nowhere. Also I cannot upload or share the model at all due to copyright.

I really need help on this and I definitely need screenshots to help explain things. I cannot duplicate or recreate the problem because again copyright reasons.

I've tried Automatic weights, I've tried envelope weights, I've tried empty groups, I've tried armature deform, I've tried everything I have found or could think of but nothing is working to fix this major issue.
[image]
Edit: Here is a quick drawing on a template to help explain it. Any loose parts such as the higher part of boots or long collars on a shirt or long hair will cause this stretching towards the center of the model to happen, regardless of direction. It's like there's a magnet near the center of the model that these loose parts are being pulled to, no matter what I do.

Comment: It very difficult to diagnose the problem without an example. Can you perhaps create a simplified example (unrelated to your copyrighted model) that exhibits the problem? Or perhaps draw some images that make it clearer what is happening?

Comment: @RichSedman I added a rough sketch to help explain the problem.

Comment: Are the 'small parts' separate meshes to the main mesh? Are they soft body/cloth? Are they parented to the main mesh? Parented to the armature? Do they have a different scale (try 'Ctrl-A'/Apply Scale)?